# insert date in a word document

Tags: datetime, vba, date, ms-word

I'm working on a Word document which has a table on each page. 
Each table contains several occurrences of the word "Datum". By double-clicking this word "Datum", this word should be replaced with the system date. 
And this date should be "frozen", i.e. it mustn't adapt itself when opening the document on a different day.

Is there anyone who can help me out with the code for this?

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using a macro button field:

- Press Ctrl + F9 to create a new field
- Enter the following text within the curly braces:

  ```
    MACROBUTTON  InsertDateTime Datum
  ```

  The result will look as follows:

  ```
    { MACROBUTTON  InsertDateTime Datum }
  ```
- Press Alt + F9 to toggle field code display

This will show Word's built-in *Insert Date* dialog. If you don't want to display the dialog you can replace `InsertDateTime` with the name of a custom VBA macro, e.g. `MyModule.MyInsertDate`. This macro would replace the field with the current date:

```
Public Sub InsertCurrentDate()
    Selection.Text = Now
End Sub
```

Comment: You can add formatting for your date in the macro if you want. i.e.** - FormatDateTime(Now, vbLongDate)** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/formatdatetime-function

Answer (score 2):

Try making each Datum a [Field](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-fields-c429bbb0-8669-48a7-bd24-bab6ba6b06bb) {MacroButton datumToDate Datum} that calls a Word VBA:

```
Sub datumToDate()
    Selection.InsertDateTime Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd")
End Sub
```

Obviously feel free to edit yyyy-mm-dd to any valid [time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx). This should use [Selection Object's InsertDateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840789.aspx) to replace the 'current selection', here your field labeled Datum. It only replaces the current Datum because it goes off of where you were when you began the Sub.

To activate MacroButton Fields, you will have to double click unless you run

```
Sub AutoOpen()
    Options.ButtonFieldClicks = 1
End Sub
```

in the ThisDocument location. I advise against this because it's easy for someone to accidentally click a Datum in an old table and reset the date to Now and I'm not positive that the Selection Method will work if you don't double click the Field (although it should).